# Should I initial LocationManager Setting in AppDelegate or in ViewController [Swift]

Tags: xcode, swift, location

I am new in IOS development.
And I am learning coreLocation and I need to initial the Location service in `ViewComtroller.swift` codes such as

> ```
> func initLocationManager() {
>     locationManager = CLLocationManager()
>     locationManager.delegate = self
>     locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 5
>     locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
>     locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
>     if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
>         print("location Services Enabled")
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> I have a question that some command such as `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` needs to run only once when the app start right? But If I add it in the `ViewDidLoad()`, it will run every time I back to the view scene.

Shall I need to put them in `AppDelegate.swift` ? I have tried to do that. But I don't know how to connect `AppDelegate.swift` with other `.swift`

does anyone know some solutions to make the app run better and efficiently

Answer (score 0):

when you get location after set this line of code locationManager.delegate = nil so its delegate methode is not called.